# (C++) IF Statements seem to simply be not working

Tags: c++

This code will only ever output the else statement, and I cannot figure out why. Of course I have tried entering 0, and it still returns using the else statement. The int seninel is defined because I was trying to use if (num = SENTINEL) to force it to execute, but it did not work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    const int SENTINEL = 0;
    cout << "Enter a number";
    cin >> num;

    if (num = 0)
    {
        cout << "It equals 0";
        system("Pause");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "it does not equal 0";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }


}
```

This is my first time using overflow and I am new to coding. Please forgive me if this post is not great. Ill reply to any questions promptly. Thank you for any potential help

Comment: Heed thy warnings ;-)

Comment: I don't have any error messages. The code compiles just fine. The only output I can ever get is the else statement though.

Comment: `if (num = 0)` is something like `if (isCrazyHumanKillingRobots = true)`. Use `==` (check for equality), not `=` (assignment).

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_operators.htm *`=` Simple assignment operator, Assigns values from right side operands to left side operand.*

Comment: So: `==` != `=`

Comment: Oh my lord haha, that worked. Thank you so much. I figured I had a simple issue here, and that was it. You're a life saver.

Comment: My problem has been solved! Thanks for the help. Once I'm better at C++ Ill be sure to repay the favor to other coders on stackOverflow.

Comment: As a technical issue, you should increase the warning level of your compiler (e.g. say  `-Wall` with gcc or `/W4` with Visual Studio) so that you see warnings like this one. You should then *understand* each and every warning (which is often not trivial, e.g. with numerical conversions) and *only then*  eliminate each and every warning.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (num = 0)
```

This assigns the value 0 to the variable called `num`. The resulting expression evaluates to 0 which, obviously, is always false.

You obviously meant to write

```
if (num == 0)
```

instead.

Comment: That was exactly the issue. Thank you for your response and help. I have been working with if statements for a minute in class, but this is the first time I have ever had to check for equality. Thank you for helping me learn a new basic skill